# Is there any short code for the change of css style of multiple id's in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Consider the set of codes I have for my three elements of ids `fill2a`, `show2`, `choice2`:

```
document.getElementById("fill2a").style.display="block"; 
document.getElementById("show2").style.display="block";
document.getElementById("choice2").style.display="block";
```

Can I replace the above code snippet into something like this? (I actually don't know the format)

```
style.display=block for ids='fill2a','show2','choice2';
```

Can I create an array and then work? Explain kindly what to do.

Comment: Best approach for this in my opinion will be to use a for loop.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try creating an array of element's id. Then iterate over them to set the style like the following way:

```
const elementIdArr = ["fill2a", "show2", "choice2"];
elementIdArr.forEach(id => document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block");
```

Answer (score 2):

Don’t address the style of the elements directly.

Write a stylesheet using classes and descendant combinators:

```css
.ancestor.active .fill,
.ancestor.active .show,
.ancestor.active .choice { display: block; }
```

Then add the class on the ancestor:

```js
document.getElementById(‘#ancestor2’).classList.add(‘active’);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a for... in loop to loop over an array of ID's:

```js
var ids = ["something", "something2", "something3"];
for (let id of ids) document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
```

```html
<a id="something">Text</a>
<a id="something2">Text</a>
<a id="something3">Text</a>
```

Comment: Since we are iterating over an array, we can use a `for...of` loop, to make it a little more concise: ```for (let id of ids) document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";```